# Distribution of $\log X$

Tags: probability

If $X$ has the density function

$$ f_\vartheta (x) = \Big \{ \begin{array}{cc}  
         (\vartheta - 1)x^{-\vartheta} & x \geq 1\\
         0 & otherwise
         \end{array}$$

How can I see that $\log X \sim Exp(\vartheta - 1)$? 
I had the idea to look at $f(\log x)$ but I think that's not right.
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, cave paintings. I'm pretty bad at those, I know... Sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry that I missed you in chat, and I didn't even really say hi to you. Hope you're okay. Best wishes, Theo

Comment: @t.b. There is a smoke signal for you. And a cave painting. Not sure you get pinged if I send you a comment but I'm going to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the cdf technique.  Let $Y = \log X$.  Then 
$$P(Y \leq y) = P(\log X \leq y) = P(X \leq e^y) = \int_1^{e^y} (\vartheta - 1)x^{-\vartheta} dx = \left.-x^{-\vartheta+1}\right|_1^{e^y} = 1-e^{-(\vartheta-1)y}.$$
Differentiating with respect to $y$ yields $(\vartheta-1) e^{-(\vartheta-1)y}$ as the pdf of $Y$, which is also the pdf of an $Exp(\vartheta - 1)$ random variable.

Comment: Don't you prefer the change of variable method? You know, the one where one computes $E(\varphi(Y))$ for every (bounded measurable) test function $\varphi$. Using cumulative distribution functions where one is given a probability density function seems like a kind of *détour*, going from the PDF of $X$ to the CDF of $X$ to the CDF of $Y$ to the PDF of $Y$, instead of going directly from the PDF of $X$ to the PDF of $Y$. Well, I guess everything works here...

Comment: @Didier: You're right, of course, that the change of variable method requires fewer steps on this problem.  When I was a student I used that method almost exclusively.  I've found, though, that the cdf technique seems to make more sense to my probability students, especially when the function defining the transformation isn't one-to-one.  So it looks like my emphasizing the cdf technique in the classroom has rubbed off on my practice.  Funny how teaching will do that to you. :)

Comment: Thanks for your very interesting answer. Students did not manage to have this effect on me. Yet... :-)